# Is it legal to reverse-engineer an integrated circuit (IC) belonging to a manufacturer

Tags: integrated-circuit, reverse-engineering

Can anyone tell me whether it is legal to reverse-engineer a chip to prove the existence of possible backdoor technologies in which the device or IC manufacturer likely is unaware of?

Comment: Depends on your legislation and has nothing to do with EE but maybe with law.se

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question.

Comment: It's legal and there are companies that do it, such as Chipworks.

Comment: @pjc50 Article by Terry Ludlow (CEO of Chipworks) [here](http://ipfrontline.com/2006/10/judicial-support-for-semiconductor-reverse-engineering-i/)

Answer (score 11):

It's perfectly legal to open up a chip and try to figure out what it does and how it does it. Good luck. I have done that to competitors' equipment to see whether they infringed any of our patents (some did, some didn't).

It's illegal having done that to copy the chip and sell the results. Regardless of whether anything inside it is patented, the whole chip design, that specific implementation, will be subject to automatic copyright.

Comment: Of course, even when you aren't breaking any laws you can still breach a contract and have civil liability.  (Validity of the contract or that particular clause might also come into question)

Comment: @Thank you to all replies. My apologies for this question being off topic. Hello Neil_UK would you be interested in helping with some chip analysis ? I would be pleased to share all the details as what we have learned about the backdoor technologies.